# Loging page doesn't load completely

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am developing a web application,I branched three separated projects from trunk after each week they are merging with trunk.

I created two website on IIS 7 named Staging and Devel,
Staging is a main version that developer and support teams can work on it and do their tests, Devel is a published version that only developer team can publish each resolved issue on it.

Staging and Devel websites are working perfectly also they have similar IIS configuration except ConnectionString.

All things are working well for these websites, I have decided to create another website named Demo for the customers' tests but there is a strange problem with IIS or maybe codes, all the IIS configuration are the same for these three WebSites, but when I want to view Demo the Loging page doesn't load good (CSS and JS), template and all images doesn't load for this reason I think the problem's reason is authentication mode or application pools on IIS but probably they can't be the main reasons because all the three website have the same configurations,
even I disabled Forms Authentication and changed Application pool also Even I checked the security on each Staging,Devel and Demo's folders but Loging page for Demo doesn't load as I want.

IIS Authentication configs for each of them is:

Anonymous and Forms Authentication are Enable.

Windows,ASP.NET impersonation,Basic Authentication and Digest Authentication are Disable.

On .NET v4 Application Pool I changed Identity mode but the result wasn't difference,
Currently Identity is "LocalSystem".

You can see

[Staging](http://staging.marcopacs.com/ngweb),
[Devel](http://devel.marcopacs.com/ngweb) each of their Loging page will be loaded successfully.

but while [Demo](http://demo.marcopacs.com/ngweb) Loging page is loading you can see the address bar and see the result, it seems is trying to authenticate,
BTW I logged the Loging's Page_Load as following:

Code:

```
Logging logging = new Logging(Global.LogPath);
logging.Log(LoggingMode.Information, "Loading Login page finished.");
```

Result:`2014-04-14 16:11:33.9817 [Warning]  [Web.Application.NGWeb.dll] Application_Start is running...
2014-04-14 16:11:36.3892 [Warning]  [Web.Application.NGWeb.dll] Application_Start performed successfully...
2014-04-14 16:11:36.4682 [Information]  [Web.Application.NGWeb.dll]
Loading Login page finished.
2014-04-14 16:11:36.5417 [Information]  [Web.Application.NGWeb.dll]
Loading Login page finished.
2014-04-14 16:11:36.5427 [Information]  [Web.Application.NGWeb.dll]
Loading Login page finished.
2014-04-14 16:11:36.5432 [Information]  [Web.Application.NGWeb.dll]
Loading Login page finished.
2014-04-14 16:11:36.5467 [Information]  [Web.Application.NGWeb.dll]
Loading Login page finished.
2014-04-14 16:11:36.5487 [Information]  [Web.Application.NGWeb.dll]
Loading Login page finished.
2014-04-14 16:11:36.5492 [Information]  [Web.Application.NGWeb.dll]
Loading Login page finished.
2014-04-14 16:11:36.5512 [Information]  [Web.Application.NGWeb.dll]
Loading Login page finished.
2014-04-14 16:11:36.5667 [Information]  [Web.Application.NGWeb.dll]
Loading Login page finished.
2014-04-14 16:11:36.5682 [Information]  [Web.Application.NGWeb.dll]
Loading Login page finished.`

the content of log file is very strange ,Loging's page_load event was fired for many times.

I don't know,I am really confused.

Any idea is truly appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A page reentrance is pretty normal if your code or configuration forces it to happen. So you provided too little information and you did too little troubleshooting. Review your configuration such as redirection, and review your code (and probably attach a debugger) to see under what scenarios this page will be entered. If you are not capable of doing so, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: @Lexi Li: Thank you, I think there is no forces, in Web config Custom Error is on like this  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Login.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"> and inside the authenticate tag <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="5000" defaultUrl="~/Account/BrowseExam.aspx" protection="All"/>, I also set index.html page as LoginUrl in Forms tag the result was same the Login.aspx all the contact doesn't load perfectly for index.

Comment: Who tells you to add <customErrors>? Please start from scratch and strictly follow Microsoft's guide, http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication/using-basic-forms-authentication-in-aspnet I can only guess so far this web application has been through too many hands and the knowledge lost along the way. Unless you clearly review all the code and configuration, you would not get it right.

Comment: Before changing mode to On I tested it many times with Off mode, there was no any occurred error, but I agree this is better it be Off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved.

I added "Everyone" permission on NGWeb folder inside Demo, I also checked the "Allow" box for "Full Control".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your ngweb folder is not accessible by anonymous users on the demo site. In your web.config you would need your authorization section to allow anonymous users, like so:

```
  <authorization>
     <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, All the web.cofig files are the same, I tested this solution but it doesn't work.